# NodeJS: How to assert if event callback function was called using sinon

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon, sinon-chai

How can I test if a callback function from a event listener is called? For example, I have the following code where app.js initializes the application through the init.js controller.

The main.js file has a class which extends and Event Emitter, making the object an event emitter.

***app.js***

```
const initController = require('./init');
async function init() {
    initController.startMain();
}
init();
```

***main.js***

```
const events = require('events'),
ui = require('./ui');

module.exports.getMain = function () {
  class Main extends events.EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.status = null;
    }
  }
  return new Main();
};

module.exports.init = () => {
  const main = this.getMain();
  ui.init(main);
  this.start(main);
}

module.exports.start = (main) => {
  ui.start(main);
  main.emit('http-init');
  main.emit('http-success');
  main.emit('http-error');
};
```

***ui.js***

```
function init(main) {
    main.on('http-init', onHttpInit.bind(this));
    main.on('http-success', onHttpSuccess.bind(this));
    main.on('http-error', onHttpError.bind(this));
    main.once('app-ready', onAppReady.bind(this));
  };

  function start (main) {};

  function onAppReady() {
    console.log('APP READY');
  };

  function onHttpInit() {
    console.log('HTTP INIT SEQUENCE');
  };

  function onHttpError(error) {
    console.log('HTTP ERROR SEQUENCE');
  };

  function onHttpSuccess() {
      console.log('HTTP SUCCESS SEQUENCE');
  };

  module.exports = exports = {
    init,
    start,
    onHttpInit,
    onHttpError,
    onHttpSuccess,
  };
```

***init.js***

```
exports.startMain = () => {

    console.log('Start application');

    // Load application modules
    const main = require('./main');

    // Start the application
    main.init();
 };
```

So, when I run the command `node app.js`, I see the following output

Start application
HTTP INIT SEQUENCE
HTTP SUCCESS SEQUENCE
HTTP ERROR SEQUENCE

which means that the listeners are active and that the functions are called.

***ui.tests.js***

```
const sinon = require('sinon'),
    main = require('../main').getMain(),
    proxyquire = require('proxyquire').noPreserveCache().noCallThru();

describe('UI Tests', () => {
    const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
    let controller = null;
    before(() => {
        controller = proxyquire('../ui', {});
    })
    describe('Testing Eventlisteners', ()=> {
        afterEach(() => {
            main.removeAllListeners();
        });
        const eventMap = new Map([
        [ 'http-init', 'onHttpInit' ],
        [ 'http-success', 'onHttpSuccess' ],
        [ 'http-error', 'onHttpError']
        ]);
        eventMap.forEach((value, key) => {
            it(`should register an eventlistener on '${key}' to ${value}`, () => {
                const stub = sinon.stub(controller, value);
                controller.init(main);
                main.emit(key);
                sinon.assert.called(stub);
            })
        })
    })
})
```

However, when I run the above test, even though I get the output, i.e. the functions were called, however, sinon assert always fails saying the below:

```
  UI Tests
    Testing Eventlisteners
HTTP INIT SEQUENCE
      1) should register an eventlistener on 'http-init' to onHttpInit
HTTP SUCCESS SEQUENCE
      2) should register an eventlistener on 'http-success' to onHttpSuccess
HTTP ERROR SEQUENCE
      3) should register an eventlistener on 'http-error' to onHttpError


  0 passing (16ms)
  3 failing

 1) UI Tests
       Testing Eventlisteners
         should register an eventlistener on 'http-init' to onHttpInit:
     AssertError: expected onHttpInit to have been called at least once but was never called
      at Object.fail (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/assert.js:106:21)
      at failAssertion (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/assert.js:65:16)
      at Object.assert.(anonymous function) [as called] (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/assert.js:91:13)
      at Context.it (test/ui.tests.js:25:30)
  2) UI Tests
       Testing Eventlisteners
         should register an eventlistener on 'http-success' to onHttpSuccess:
     AssertError: expected onHttpSuccess to have been called at least once but was never called
      at Object.fail (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/assert.js:106:21)
      at failAssertion (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/assert.js:65:16)
      at Object.assert.(anonymous function) [as called] (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/assert.js:91:13)
      at Context.it (test/ui.tests.js:25:30)

  3) UI Tests
       Testing Eventlisteners
         should register an eventlistener on 'http-error' to onHttpError:
     AssertError: expected onHttpError to have been called at least once but was never called
      at Object.fail (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/assert.js:106:21)
      at failAssertion (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/assert.js:65:16)
      at Object.assert.(anonymous function) [as called] (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/assert.js:91:13)
      at Context.it (test/ui.tests.js:25:30)
```

I do not know why the tests fail even though the function was called at least once, which is seen by the outputs `HTTP INIT SEQUENCE`, `HTTP SUCCESS SEQUENCE` and `HTTP ERROR SEQUENCE` when I run the tests.

I tried doing `stub.should.have.been.called;`. With this the tests pass, however, it's not really passing the tests as both `stub.should.have.been.called;` or `stub.should.not.have.been.called;` pass the test regardless, instead of the latter failing the test.

Anybody know the reason for this failing test? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run `const stub = sinon.stub(controller, value);` to stub the values exported by your `ui` module. This does change the values exported by the module, but the problem is with this code inside your `ui` module:

```
function init(main) {
    main.on('http-init', onHttpInit.bind(this));
    main.on('http-success', onHttpSuccess.bind(this));
    main.on('http-error', onHttpError.bind(this));
    main.once('app-ready', onAppReady.bind(this));
}
```

From the perspective of this code `module.exports` *is* mutated by your calls `sinon.stub(controller, value)` but **this does not change the values of the symbols `onHttpInit`, `onHttpSuccess`, etc. symbols in the code above because these are symbols that are local to the scope of the `ui` module**. You can mutate `module.exports` as much as you want: it still has no effect on the code above.

You could change your code to this:

```
function init(main) {
    main.on('http-init', exports.onHttpInit.bind(this));
    main.on('http-success', exports.onHttpSuccess.bind(this));
    main.on('http-error', exports.onHttpError.bind(this));
    main.once('app-ready', exports.onAppReady.bind(this));
}
```

You can use `exports` directly because you assign the same value to both `module.exports` and `exports` with `module.exports = exports = ...`

This change should fix the immediate issue you ran into. However, I'd modify the testing approach here. Your tests are titled `should register an eventlistener on '${key}' to ${value}` but really what your are testing is not merely that an event listener has been registered but that event propagation works. In effect, you are testing the functionality of that `EventEmitter` is responsible for providing. I'd change the tests to stub the `on` method of your `main` object and verify that it has been called with the appropriate values. Then the test would test what it actually advertises.

Comment: True, it is testing that, however, when I do function init(main) {
    main.on('http-init', exports.onHttpInit.bind(this));
    main.on('http-success', exports.onHttpSuccess.bind(this));
    main.on('http-error', exports.onHttpError.bind(this));
    main.once('app-ready', exports.onAppReady.bind(this));
}

I get the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
      at Object.init (ui.js:5:45)

However, apparently when I changed it to this.onHttpInit.bind(this), the tests seem to pass.

Comment: I did not notice that `onAppReady` is not exported. You cannot use replace it with `exports.onAppReady`, *because it is not exported*. That's why you get the error. Either you export it like the other event handlers, or you leave it as is but if you decide to leave it as is then you cannot stub it in testing.

Comment: I do see that using 'this' instead of 'exports' also works there. Would there be any difference in those?

Comment: If `onAppReady` is not exported, you cannot either `exports.onAppReady` nor `this.onAppReady`. If I use the code you've shown and just modify it to use `exports` like I've shown in my answer, or I modify it to use `this` like you did, then *in either case* I get an error when it tries to do call `bind` for `onAppReady`. Here's the immediate difference between using `exports` and `this` in the code you've shown. Consider this usage: `const { init } = require("../ui");` If you use `exports`, the call `init(main)` will work. If you use `this`, `init(main)` won't work because `this` won't be set.

Comment: Yes, that I changed. I was curious about the other ones.

Answer (score 1):

you are registering the main callbacks prior to stubbing, so the stubbed functions are not what is called, only the original functions.  Try reversing the order in your it function:

```
        eventMap.forEach((value, key) => {
            it(`should register an eventlistener on '${key}' to ${value}`, () => {
                const stub = sinon.stub(controller, value);
                controller.init(main);
                main.emit(key);
                sinon.assert.called(stub);
            })
        })
```

---

It also appears you are requiring main without using proxyquire.  So then it would never be picking up the stub.  A couple solutions: 1) rework main to take UI as a argument (i.e. dependency injection) in which case your tests could pass the stub to main; or 2) require main with proxyquire so you can force it to require the stubbed version.  Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: This is not working as well, still get the same issue and the same output as above.

Comment: Solution 1 is not really possible as the application has more controllers that work similar to UI, for Solution 2, how would you proxyquire the main singleton? I am not completely sure about it. I do understand what you are saying, but I am not sure how I would do it.

Comment: I will work up a complete test example for you - been swamped today

Comment: Hi @DDupont, were you able to look into it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I do not about sinon, but the jest has same functionality called [mock functions](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions).

And jest has faced the same issue due to export https://medium.com/@DavideRama/mock-spy-exported-functions-within-a-single-module-in-jest-cdf2b61af642. Because of your export `getMain`,`init` and `start` in *main.js* and using `getMain` and `start` inside `init`.

Instead try to move `getMain` and `start` to separate module and export and test it. Let me know if issues still appears

Comment: Do you mean the issue here is that all init, start and getMain are in the same module and that's messing up with the unit tests?

Comment: Yes, but also because one is called inside of another.

Comment: Well, it is going to be difficult to fix then, well at least not without making a lot of changes at the source code of the application, as it is quite big and cannot really change the code without discussions, thanks for the insight though. :)

Answer (score 0):

After a week of questions and tests, I have found a solution. It was a bit of a combination of solutions from DDupont and Louis. The first change the following, in the **ui.js** file, add `this.` to the bind

```
function init(main) {
    main.on('http-init', this.onHttpInit.bind(this));
    main.on('http-success', this.onHttpSuccess.bind(this));
    main.on('http-error', this.onHttpError.bind(this));
    main.once('app-ready', this.onAppReady.bind(this));
  };
```

And like DDupont said, in the unit test, move `controller.init(main)` after the stub

```
eventMap.forEach((value, key) => {
            it(`should register an eventlistener on '${key}' to ${value}`, () => {
                const stub = sinon.stub(controller, value);
                controller.init(main);
                main.emit(key);
                sinon.assert.called(stub);
            })
        })
```

Thank you for all the help.